# Why doesn't my audio play on Windows 10 PCs any longer?

Tags: java

I'm encountering an odd audio playback issue.   My code is running perfectly on the Mac where I developed it and was running on the Windows 10 PCs where it was deployed until this week.   I'm not aware of any changes made to these Windows PCs.

My development Mac and the Windows PCs both have OpenJDK 11.0.2 installed.   When the code now runs on the Windows PCs I receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
        at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:425)
        at bob.Player.play(Player.java:26)
        at bob.Player.main(Player.java:57)
```

The code I'm using as a test is:

```
URL audioUrl = new URL("https://(server FQDN)/audiopath/test.wav");
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioUrl);
AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
//AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 1, 2, 44100, false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
SourceDataLine audioLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
audioLine.open(format);
audioLine.start();
byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1; 
while ((bytesRead = audioStream.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1) {
    audioLine.write(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
audioLine.drain();
audioLine.close();
audioStream.close();
```

I've tried to manually set the audio parameters instead of using getFormat(), but that made no difference.

Does anyone know why Windows 10 wouldn't play this audio?   The code was running fine until last week.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: You have a 44.1khz 16-bit MONO audio file? **Why**?

Comment: They aren’t files I’ve created, they are part of a series of audio files used to train people on using Steno machines.  I’m only writing the software, not creating the audio.

Comment: Search for "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface" and you will find many others. Seems to be a common problem over plenty of years. My guess is that something have changed on the Windows Box. Maybe try on another Windows?

Comment: Yep, I noticed that as well.  Oddly, this problem is occurring on 24 computers in this lab.  No windows updates applied, no Java updates applied.  This makes no sense whatsoever.   The same code continues to run perfectly under MacOS with the same version of OpenJDK.